# How to cache expressjs response

Tags: node.js, caching, express

How to cache the response that was genereated by expressjs route. This route has a lot of database access and changes to it to it are very little. Is there any  node module avaialble.

Thanks

Comment: You want a client to cache it, or do you want to cache the response server-side for subsequent requests by different clients?

Comment: my bad-- cache the response server-side for subsequent request for different clients.

Answer (score 4):

[connect-cache](https://github.com/tdebarochez/connect-cache) should do the trick. Add this to your app as a middleware

```
var connect_cache = require('connect-cache');
app.use(
connect_cache({rules: [{regex: /.*/, ttl: 60000}]})
);
```